# Report Region based on POP-LOV in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Hi to all respected gurus.

I have a POP-UP LOV in Oracle APEX Form. I want to have a report region to retrieve data from another table, against selected value in POP-UP LOV.

Please guide me, how to do it?

**Information Related to Form**  
 
 "JO Number" is the POP-UP LOV based on table CPS_JO contains information Job Order Description and Vendor Name. I want to retrieve Job Order Description and Vendor Name against selected JO Number.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards
Muhammad Uzair Awan

Comment: apex version? Interactive report? Classic report? If classic, why not interactive with a sql that joins the 2 tables? What do you have right now? Do you have the select list or popup in place? Do you know how to use items in queries and do you understand session state? All in all, it would seem you don't completely understand the basics of apex. Did you have a look through the 2-day developer guide for example? Read some documentation?

Answer (score 0):

1. Item names cannot contain spaces, so I will assume your pop up LOV is called **JO_NUMBER**.
2. You can refer to the selected value in **JO_NUMBER** by using `:JO_NUMBER` in your SQL. So the region source for the report would look something like this:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_TABLE WHERE COLUMN_NAME = :JO_NUMBER
   ```

I advise going through the 2 day developer guide as Tom suggested above.

Comment: I would also advice to keep page number inside name of element for example :P6_JO_NUMBER. It allows to navigate to item more easy across multiple-paged application.